# XNA Per-Polygon Collision Check

Tags: xna, collision-detection, 3d-meshes, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a project in XNA for WP7 with a low-poly environment, my problem is I need to setup a working per-polygon collision check between 2 or more 3d meshes.

I've checked tons of tutorials but all of them use bounding-boxes, bounding-spheres,rays etc., but what I really need is a VERY precise way of checking if the polygons of two distinct models have intersected or not.

If you could redirect me to an example or at least give me some pointers I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at:

1. http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html
2. http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialB.html

Also look for the term: AAOB rather than AABB.

SAT (or Separating Axis Theorem) is also a good start, it's an approach to detect and solve collisions between objects of any shape. Refer to: http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55

Comment: That's certainly a heavy read, but thank you.

Comment: It still amazes me that I can't find a working example in xna, it's not that i'm lazy or anything, but I always learn better through examples.